# Longest sentence where all words are anagrams of each other

Tags: english, anagram, letters, open-ended

> Won, now own.

Rules:

1. 1. A “word” is an entry on [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/).
   2. A “sentence” is any text that is grammatically correct, has a complete meaning in the English language, starts with a capital letter and ends with a dot.
2. Repeated words are not allowed.
3. You are allowed to use punctuation, such as colons and quotation marks, as long as it’s not for making lists (i.e. cheating).
4. Sentences are rated by word count, however proper names count each as only one word since they can trivially be extended from simple proper nouns by appending surnames.
5. Common words cannot be changed to proper nouns, although these are allowed as long as they appear as such on dictionary.com.
6. Finally, as suggested, sentences and text inside quotes must actually make sense, not just gibberish.

That’s it! Good luck, puzzlers!

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate of another question here...

Comment: Shouldn't there be a requirement that you form a proper sentence, not just gibberish?

Comment: [This might be useful](https://www.reddit.com/r/answers/comments/13o511/what_is_the_word_with_the_most_anagrams/) to people attempting this puzzle.

Comment: You've defined *word*, but not *sentence*. Do you require a finite verb?

Comment: Non-finite verbs are fine

Comment: Competitions to form sentences with the most X inevitably devolve into who can stretch the meaning of sentence the most, and writing code to brute-force search.

Comment: I would not call any of the answers sentences.

Comment: Is it strange how saying sentences backward creates backward sentences saying how strange it is?

Comment: I have a 1-long word sentence : "Help !". That fit every rules. :D

Comment: @Therandomguy - not very long though is it? ;-)

Comment: now to construct these into a sentence: [source](https://www.reddit.com/r/answers/comments/13o511/what_is_the_word_with_the_most_anagrams/)  adeinr (52 anagrams): adrien, adrine, ainder, anderi, andire, andrei, andrie, ardine, dairen, daneri, danier, darein, darien, darine, dearin, deiran, denair, denari, denira, derain, derian, derina, dierna, draine, drenai, drenia, edrian, erandi, eridan, erinda, idanre, indear, indera, naderi, nadier, nadire, nareid, neidar, neriad, nerida, niedra, radien, raiden, rained, randie, rdeina, readin, redian, redina, renida, riande, rienda

Comment: The title is very misleading. From the title I assumed all words in the sentence had to be anagrams of each other but the rules don't require it.

Comment: You should probably add a rule that restricts lists. Otherwise, with @SeanC 's anagrams of "ADEINR" and abusing rule #5, I can easily do:

"Andrei rained [list all noun anagrams of ADEINR here]" for a grammatically correct sentence.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko I think the title is part of the rules, and hence the rules in the body do not include that. But good catch!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**11 words, 77 characters**

> Anestri-resiant starnie retina's stearin stainer retains antsier, nastier retsina ratines.

Which means:

Having been resiant (residing) in anestri (a period of sexual rest), 
the stearin stainer (a pigment used to stain stearin, a certain triglyceride compound)
of the retina of a starnie (a small star) retains
retsina ratines (loose, knotted fabric soaked in retsina, a pine-flavoured Greek wine)
that are more fidgety (antsier) and more nastier than before.

Comment: I know a lot of words, but wow, good thing you had your explanation.

Comment: 90 characters after you add the punctuation. Very nice.

Comment: You're going to have to explain exactly what a star's retina is.

Comment: It's the colorless-green part of a star that sleeps furiously =) Alternatively, we can interpret "starnie" as "starlet", a young actor / actress.

Answer (score 26):

> Setal teals steal least-stale slate-stela Tesla tales.

9 words

"Bristly birds steal the least stale tales of Tesla that are written on a slate stela (stone slab)."

Comment: I like this one better than the spear one, it makes a bit more sense (lol) if that's in any way logical...

Comment: Um... 9 5-letter words should be 45 characters??

Answer (score 9):

Here's a five-word one:

> Rats' star tars tsar arts.

Or, "The most famous from among the rats smears tar on art produced by the emperor."

Comment: The apostrophe at the end of " Rats' " is cheating a bit, an anagram of that would have to have the apostrophe as well. Clever though.

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah An alternative would be "Rats" star, indicating the star of the musical "Rats". I'm not quite willing to stoop down to that level, though. :D

Comment: Yeah, I am not even sure if non-alphabet characters matter in anagrams. Depends on the definition I guess.

Comment: The question says punctuation is allowed.

Answer (score 9):

8 words:

> Parse, "Asper spear pares prase, apres, reaps pears".

Meaning "Parse the sentence: "rough spear cuts/removes prase (a translucent, greenish variety of chalcedony.), afterwards it reaps pears". Convoluted, I know.

Comment: Actually, since the rules are not clear on what counts as a sentence, one can do: > Parse "apers, apres, asper, pares, pears, prase, presa, rapes, reaps, spare, spear".  which could be a command to parse that string, it wouldn't really matter if the words inside the string form a proper sentence,

Comment: This would be a command to parse a list. But I see where you are going: You could put any gibberish inside the quotes. I'll change the rules to dis

Comment: Probably needs a comma replacing with a semicolon in here

Comment: Corrected the sentence  ;)

Answer (score 8):

6 6-letter words, no punctuation:

> `Septal plates staple palest pastel petals.`

which means:

Plates from a burial chamber use a stapler on pale, delicately shaded petals.

Comment: I remember trying to write a sestina once with all of the line-ending words anagrams; five of the six were these. I wish I had finished it.

Comment: @justhalf You still could.. It's never too late :) And there's "pleats" too, I just couldn't fit it in anywhere.

Comment: I think you meant @ThomasKwa instead :)

Comment: @justhalf Oops.. Sorry about that..

Comment: @ThomasKwa You still could.. It's never too late :) And there's "pleats" too, I just couldn't fit it in anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

**9 words, 54 characters**

> Artel's salter alerts staler slater, alters stelar estral ratels.

Which means-

A salter (a person making salts) who belongs to an artel (a community of
    farmers), alerts a slater (a person who lays slates) who is staler (more 
    unwitty), and alters an inscription of estral ratels (badgerlike carnivores 
    who are in the estrous cycle) on a stone slub (stele).

There are also the words "talers" and "laster" which I am not able to fit in this sentence(?) meaningfully.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an 8 word sentence with a proper noun:

> Apres-rapes, Spear pares spare pears; reaps asper.

You didn't say I couldn't make one or all of them proper nouns!

Comment: Well pointed out. I changed the rules because it's kinda cheating. Have my upvote, though

Answer (score 3):

10 words

> Apres-rapes, parse "prase spear pares spare pears, reaps asper"

meaning

> After you have completed the violent sexual attacks, analyse the following sentence: "a weapon, made of green quartz, removes the skin of sweet fruits (rather like apples) which are additional to requirements, and is rewarded with a former silver coin of Turkey and Egypt"

Thank you to @Ian McDonald for the helpful link.

Update: I see Respect has come up with something similar while I was working this out.